# React Native expo youtube player

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm working on reactNative expo app and I want to add YouTube player like [YouTube-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-youtube-sdk) component in ReactNative CLI.
I tried adding Webview component it worked perfectly but it's not efficient as YouTube-sdk.

Is there any way to do it or I have to use Webview component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](https://github.com/LonelyCpp/react-native-youtube-iframe) solution it's worked perfectly for me.